# copy entire file to clipboard (but not default, +, or * registry) in Linux xterm

Tags: linux, ssh, copy-paste, xterm

I am trying to copy 13,000 lines of code from a file on a remote computer to a text file on my own computer but am having no luck. I am working on a Linux virtual box and am ssh'd into another computer where the file is. If I highlight with my mouse and type control shift C, then it works, but I can't highlight anything other than what's currently visible in the window. Using   `g g "` + `y G`  or `" + y`  (in vi) doesn't work because the + (or *) registry doesn't transfer between the remote system and mine (using Visual select and then control Shift C doesn't seem to work either). Does anyone know how to select more than just the visible window so I don't have to copy paste hundreds of times to get the whole file?

Comment: if you downvote, please feel free to tell me how I can improve my question. I'd be more than willing to change it, but I can't until I know what's wrong with it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy the whole file using this code:

```
scp username@remote:/path/to/file /local/path/to/destination
```

Note : here your destination is where you are logged in (local computer)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!